# How can I store a String with escape characters without turning the escape characters into their substitutes?

Tags: java, string, escaping

I'm writing a Java-based program that downloads a JavaScript file from GitHub, parses it into a String, and then pushes it to a MediaWiki site. The problem is that the JS file has fairly complicated regex in it, and Java is parsing it into escape characters (e.g. `[^\S\r\n]` getting parsed into `/\s`). Is there a way I can store a String without these escape characters being activated?

EDIT: The code:

```
package org.wikipedia.afchbuddy;

import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

/**
 * This is a bot script designed to allow sysops to push releases for AFCH
 * on-wiki.
 *
 * @author Nathan2055
 */
public class AFCHBuddy {

    private static String username;
    private static String password;
    private static String location;
    private static String buffer;
    private static String error = "An error occured trying to access and write to Wikipedia. If you report this error, please provide the following debug info:";
    private static String basescript = "https://raw.github.com/WPAFC/afch/develop/src/";
    private static String basescript_stable = "https://raw.github.com/WPAFC/afch/master/src/";
    private static String mediawikilocation = "MediaWiki:Gadget-afchelper.js";

    /**
     * The main bot script.
     *
     * @param args This program accepts three command line arguments, 0 is the
     * push location (stable, beta, or testwiki), 1 is your username, and 2 is
     * your password.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            err.println("Incorrect number of arguments. Please see the README for more information.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        location = args[0];
        username = args[1];
        password = args[2];

        switch (location) {
            case "testwiki":
                build("testwiki");
                break;
            case "beta":
                build("beta");
                break;
            case "stable":
                build("stable");
                break;
            default:
                err.println("Error: Unknown build location.");
                System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method does the actual work of performing the edits.
     *
     * @param destarg The destination wiki.
     */
    private static void build(String destarg) {
        Wiki wiki;
        try {
            if ("testwiki".equals(destarg)) {
                wiki = new Wiki("test.wikipedia.org");
            } else {
                wiki = new Wiki();
            }

            wiki.login(username, password);

            downloadFile(basescript + "MediaWiki:Gadget-afchelper.js", "afch.js");
            buffer = readFile("afch.js");
            wiki.edit(mediawikilocation, buffer, "Update afch.js using AFCHBuddy");

            downloadFile(basescript + "MediaWiki:Gadget-afchelper.css", "afch.css");
            buffer = readFile("afch.css");
            wiki.edit("MediaWiki:Gadget-afchelper.css", buffer, "Update afch.css using AFCHBuddy");

            downloadFile(basescript + "core.js", "core.js");
            buffer = readFile("core.js");
            wiki.edit(mediawikilocation + "/core.js", buffer, "Update core.js using AFCHBuddy");

            downloadFile(basescript + "redirects.js", "redirects.js");
            buffer = readFile("redirects.js");
            wiki.edit(mediawikilocation + "/redirects.js", buffer, "Update redirects.js using AFCHBuddy");

            downloadFile(basescript + "submissions.js", "submissions.js");
            buffer = readFile("submissions.js");
            wiki.edit(mediawikilocation + "/submissions.js", buffer, "Update submissions.js using AFCHBuddy");

            downloadFile(basescript + "ffu.js", "ffu.js");
            buffer = readFile("ffu.js");
            wiki.edit(mediawikilocation + "/ffu.js", buffer, "Update ffu.js using AFCHBuddy");

            wiki.logout();

            err.println("Files syncronized successfully.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException | LoginException e) {
            err.println(error);
            e.printStackTrace(err);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts a file to a String.
     *
     * @param path This accepts the path of the file to be processed in String
     * form.
     * @return The output String.
     * @throws IOException The exception if something goes wrong while reading
     * the file.
     */
    private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
    }

    /**
     * This downloads the input URL and saves it to dest.
     *
     * @param URL The file's location on the internet.
     * @param dest The file's soon to be location on your computer.
     * @throws IOException The exception if something goes wrong while
     * processing.
     */
    private static void downloadFile(String URL, String dest) throws IOException {
        URL website = new URL(URL);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should not happen.  Show us your code.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing your code.  Probably the problem is whatever "parses it into a string".  If you simply take the byte array you download and turn that into a string with the proper encoding (probably UTF-8), \n and such should not be altered (\uNNN unicode escapes might be, though).  Probably whatever you are using to parse it is being too clever.  Try to get the raw bytes and do no more than converting to a String and you should be fine.

Comment: @SLaks - Added my code.

Comment: Now please indicate which part of your code *is parsing ... into escape characters*.

Comment: @PM77-1 - readFile(). It converts the file to a String, which I assume converts the escape characters. Am I wrong in this assumption?